# Laravel 4 retrieval

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got a function in my User model (I use Laravel's default User model) that is a relationship with the Player model.

I want to retrieve the id of the Player, but I can't. Is there anyway to do it? I've tried something like:

```
Auth::user()->players->id;
```

or

```
Auth::user()->id->players;
```

but it doesn't work. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the type of your relationship. From the code you provided I can guess that the relationship is called 'players' and not 'player' (meaning you should have a players() function inside your User model). If this is the case, than your code

```
Auth::user()->players
```

returns a collections of players. You can loop through this collection and get IDs of the players:

```
foreach (Auth::user()->players as $player)
{
    $playerId = $player->id;
    // Do more stuff for a single player here
}
```

Hope this clarifies things a little bit. If not, please provide more details about your relationship between User and Player models.
You can also find more details here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Comment: da nisi hrvat? I did all of that, I'm creating some kind of guild (http://paste.laravel.com/JWI), how could I input the ID there? Do I need a foreach there?

Comment: Crnogorac :) Are you sure the logic of your relationship between User and Player is correct? Why does one user have more players? Is a user actually a player himself/herself? If so, than you either don't need User or you don't need Player model, you can work with one and then: $guild->ownerid = Auth::user()->id;

Comment: One user can have more players, but a user isn't actually a player himself/herself. If it was like that, it would be easy lol. That's what the problem is.

Comment: Then one of the user's players needs to be guild owner, right? If so, as I wrote in the answer, Auth::user()->players is a collection that you can iterate through and choose one player which will be the guild owner.

Comment: yes, I got that. But I'm creating a guild, I suppose I cannot do a foreach in there.